# Selenium invalid argument

Tags: selenium, webdriver, codeception

I'm trying to set up codeception.

When running any acceptance tests i get the following error:

```
> 1) FirstCest: Test
 Test  tests\acceptance\FirstCest.php:tryToTest

  [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException] invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.92)


Scenario Steps:

 1. $I->amOnPage("/") at tests\acceptance\FirstCest.php:14

#1  C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Test\Programming test\vendor\php-webdriver\webdriver\lib\Exception\WebDriverException.php:99
#2  C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Test\Programming test\vendor\php-webdriver\webdriver\lib\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.php:370
#3  C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Test\Programming test\vendor\php-webdriver\webdriver\lib\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.php:590
#4  C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Test\Programming test\vendor\php-webdriver\webdriver\lib\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.php:252
#5  Codeception\Module\WebDriver->amOnPage
#6  C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Test\Programming test\tests\_support\_generated\AcceptanceTesterActions.php:305
#7  C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Test\Programming test\tests\acceptance\FirstCest.php:14
#8  FirstCest->tryToTest
Artifacts:

Png: C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Test\Programming test\tests/_output\FirstCest.tryToTest.fail.png
Html: C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Test\Programming test\tests/_output\FirstCest.tryToTest.fail.html

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
PS C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Test\Programming test>
```

Here is my config:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
colors: true
modules: 
    enabled:
        - WebDriver
        - Asserts
        - \Helper\Acceptance
    config:
        WebDriver:
            url: 'www.google.com'
            browser: 'chrome'
            window_size: 1280x1280
            wait: 10
```

Im running chrome 81.

and I start my selenium-standalone server like so

`java -jar .\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar`

What argument am I mmissing ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why is this tagged with Composer?

Comment: Random guess - you missed http:// part of the url.

Comment: Can you ad your comment as your answer because it was a very helpful solution! I wish you a good week sir!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WebDriver url parameter must be a valid URL and start with a scheme - `http://` or `https://`.